# MySQL query to calculate difference between two days and insert that value into column in same table

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have considered a start date as '11th July 2014 2:00 AM' (explained below). I have other column in same table where I have values stored in the format "YYYY:DD:MM Min:Sec". I want to subtract each entry from this table from start date and insert it into new column called 'Day'. Here is the query I am trying to execute:

```
set @start = '2014-07-11 02:00:00';

use rawlog;
insert into  api_raw(`day`)
VALUES
(date_diff(DAY, start, #column_name)
```

I do not understand the error I am getting. Where I am going wrong in this one? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: there is no function called `date_diff` in mysql, I think you are looking at `timestampdiff`

Comment: timestampdiff is also not working. Please make a note that start has been defined and is not a column name. Thanks for suggestion though.

Comment: So you don't store hours?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
DATEDIFF (DATE(@start),DATE(#column_name))
```

rather than

```
date_diff(DAY, start, #column_name)
```

Comment: I guess I am getting it wrong some where. Error says "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'start' in 'field list'"

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention.. 2nd parameter is not coulmn_name but rather a date time value in format of start (YYYY:DD:MM MM:SS)

Comment: @DotNetNewBie I don't understand this comment

Comment: value of both parameters in function datediff is of format '2014-07-11 02:00:0' . Do I still have to use Date() in this case?

Comment: Use @start, it will work and I have used DATE() function to remove time from DATETIME only. So don't worry.